# setSelection not works onClickListener with ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've a ListView on the left, and a empty View on the right of the screen.

Firstly, when the app starts, the first item of the ListView is selected automatically with this code (I know that I can delete some lines):

```
... onCreate(..){
...
    lv.clearFocus();
    lv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.requestFocusFromTouch();
            lv.setSelected(true);
            lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            lv.setItemChecked(posicion, true);
            lv.setSelection(posicion);
        }
    });
....
}
```

Now, I want that when users clicks on the empty view, the selected item is the next on the ListView. I have this code, but it not works:

```
... onCreate(..){
...
emptyview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lv.clearFocus();
            position++;
            if (position == t.length) position = 0;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.requestFocusFromTouch();
            lv.setSelected(true);
            lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            lv.setItemChecked(position, true);
            lv.setSelection(position);
        }
    });
....
}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks so much!